# Compare to dates Javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, comparison

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Compare 2 dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-2-dates-with-javascript)

Hi,
I'm working on form validation for my application and i want to know where i would be to start looking at to find date comparison eg a start date and an end date. The dates inputted in to my application are in the form: DD/MM/YYYY. 
Thanks in Advance,
Dean

Comment: You may want to check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-2-dates-with-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the [Javascript Date object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp), you can simply do:

```
var startDate = new Date();
var endDate = getEndDate();

if (endDate < startDate)
    alert("Houston, we've got a problem!");
```

**EDIT**: Changed naming a bit just to stick to camelCase convention, even though I despise it.

Answer (score 0):

this function lets you convert dates to timestamps with wich you could work:
http://caioariede.com/arquivos/strtotime.js

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll want to parse the text into `Date` objects, then use the language's built-in date comparison.  For example:

```
var dateStr = document.getElementById('foo').value;
var date = Date.parse(dateStr);

var dateStr2 = document.getElementById('foo2').value;
var date2 = Date.parse(dateStr2);

if (date < date2) {
    // ...
}
```